How to display all items in a SharePoint list?
Note: I just started playing with SharePoint code on the side.
Hi,
Is there an easy way to dump all the items in a SharePoint list? I'd like to dump each item row by row. Later on, I was thinking of setting the LastName if a record matches. Since I don't know anything, is there a way to dump all the data in each item?
I can connect to the SP Site and get the List and dump the field names. But when I try to iterate the list using the field.InternalNames but it gives me an error.
I am writing this as a C# Plugin to a Dynamics CRM. Using SPClient.
Here is my snippet and output:
SP.ClientContext          l_context  = new SP.ClientContext(https://sharepointsite/);
SP.List                   list       = l_context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Claim");
SP.CamlQuery              query      = SP.CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
SP.ListItemCollection     items      = list.GetItems(query);
l_context.Load(items);
l_context.ExecuteQuery();
_tracingService.Trace("\n\ncount " + items.Count + "\n\n");
foreach (SP.ListItem listItem in items)
{
               //dump list here
 

               //_tracingService.Trace(listItem["Title"].ToString());
               //_tracingService.Trace(listItem["LastName"].ToString());
}

Output:
count 430

 
Error Message:
Unhandled exception:
Exception type: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.InvalidPluginExecutionException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at SharePointTest.WorkflowClass1.Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
-- End stack trace --

Questions are:

How can I dump all the data in each row/item/record?
How can I access each field?
Does the items.count include more than the records? Seems the count is higher than what I can see in SP.

Thanks a lot!
Gary
